# Can't assign id as variable to jade template

Tags: html, templates, pug, mustache, hogan.js

When doing this:

```
div(id=player)
  ul.timeline
    {{#epochs}}
    li.epoch {{epoch}}
    {{/epochs}}
```

and render it with hogan

```
html = ss.tmpl['board'].render({ //ss is for socketstream, it uses hogan.
  epochs: treeStructure,
  player: "player2"
});
```

I get the following error

```
! Errror formatting Jade template
/Users/ilyadorman/dev/game/client/templates/board.jade:2
    1| div(id=player)
  > 2|   ul.timeline
    3|     {{#epochs}}
    4|     li.epoch {{epoch}}
    5|     {{/epochs}}

player is not defined
```

But when I do `{{player}}` it works fine! What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says, `player` is not defined within the context you are trying to use it in.

You could put single or double quotes around `player` and then it would be defined-- as a primitive string.

Like `div(id='player')`.

If that's what you want.  If you want the div's id to be dynamically altered with the variable then you should use the double curlies for that to be passed in.

These are different programmatic contexts. You can define variables within a Jade template and perform operations on them, but these are different from the variables passed *in*, which in Hogan/Mustache are called tags.  In this case, you want the tags.

I've never tried anything like this, but something along the lines of

`div(id='{{player}}')`

should work.

Comment: I did mix up between jade and mustache - the variable belonged to hogan and jade had no idea about it. So I did `- var player = '{{player}}'`